# Shift weekend dates to last weekday in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have pyspark dataframe, in which data column is there, which has weekend dates as well. I just want to change these dates to previous or next working days.

```
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
columns = ['Date', 'id', 'dogs', 'cats']
vals = [('04-05-2018',1, 2, 0), ('05-05-2018',2, 0, 1), ('06-05-2018',2, 0, 1)]
df = spark.createDataFrame(vals, columns)
df.show()
```

DataFrame look like:

```
+----------+---+----+----+
|      Date| id|dogs|cats|
+----------+---+----+----+
|04-05-2018|  1|   2|   0|
|05-05-2018|  2|   0|   1|
|06-05-2018|  2|   0|   1|
+----------+---+----+----+
```

Now, i'm able to identify the weekday, as in separate column

```
df = df.withColumn('Date', unix_timestamp(df['Date'].cast("string"), 'dd-MM-yyyy').cast("double").cast('timestamp').cast('date'))
df = df.select('Date', date_format('Date', 'u').alias('dow_number'), 'id', 'dogs', 'cats')
temp = df
temp.show()

+----------+----------+---+----+----+
|      Date|dow_number| id|dogs|cats|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+
|2018-05-04|         5|  1|   2|   0|
|2018-05-05|         6|  2|   0|   1|
|2018-05-06|         7|  2|   0|   1|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+
```

Now i just want to shift the data to last working day or next working day if it is on weekend, means i want my dataframe to be like this:

```
+----------+----------+---+----+----+
|      Date|dow_number| id|dogs|cats|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+
|2018-05-04|         5|  1|   2|   0|
|2018-05-04|         5|  2|   0|   1|
|2018-05-04|         5|  2|   0|   1|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Missing imports: e.g. `from pyspark.sql.functions import date_format`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the dow_number generated, you can apply condition to check and subtract date using date_sub(),

```
df = df.withColumn('Date1',F.when(df['dow_number'] == 6,F.date_sub(df.Date,1)).when(df['dow_number'] == 7,F.date_sub(df.Date,2)).otherwise(df.Date))

+----------+----------+---+----+----+----------+
|      Date|dow_number| id|dogs|cats|     Date1|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+----------+
|2018-05-04|         5|  1|   2|   0|2018-05-04|
|2018-05-05|         6|  2|   0|   1|2018-05-04|
|2018-05-06|         7|  2|   0|   1|2018-05-04|
+----------+----------+---+----+----+----------+
```

I believe, you don't need dow_number to change as well.If you need, either you can use date_format on new date and get it (or) apply another condition as above. Hope this helps!

Comment: what is `F` here?

Comment: Missing imports: e.g. `import pyspark.sql.functions as F`